# How to determine why system wakeup occurred

Tags: macos, cocoa

Is it possible to determine the cause of system wakeup from sleep in OS X from Cocoa, a lower-level API method, or a terminal command (less preferable)?  Possible reasons for wakeup include:

- A keyboard button was pressed
- The laptop lid was opened
- Network activity was detected
- A scheduled wakeup time (set with IOPMSchedulePowerEvent) occurred

I am trying in particular to detect the last reason, so that I can put the system to sleep for 10 minutes and then automatically into hibernation (aka safe sleep).  To do so, I am scheduling a wakeup 10 minutes out, followed by a hibernate event.  But I don't want to accidentally hibernate the system if the user activated a wakeup at roughly the same time.

FYI, this is apparently [possible in Windows 7](http://www.cravingtech.com/fix-windows-vista7-sleep-mode-from-waking-up-by-itself.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminal commands `pmset -g log` and `pmset -g rawlog` should help do what you need.

The [manual for pmset](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/pmset.1.html) documents these options; note the manual page shipped with Mac OS X 10.7 lists many more options.